# Join two queries from the same table - SELECT DISTINCT?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, distinct

I have two tables linked by an `AUTO_KEY` field, from one table I'm retrieving the number (id), from the other I get several statuses by number(id), each status has a date associated to it.
I need to restrict the results only to the maximum/latest date for all numbers(ids) and the corresponding status

```
SELECT
    OPERATION.NUMBER, 
    STATUS.STATUS, 
    Max(STATUS.DATE)

FROM 
   STATUS, 
   OPERATION

WHERE 
OPERATION.AUTO_KEY = STATUS.AUTO_KEY
```

From here

```
Number  Status    Date
-----------------------------
1       A       10/20/13
1       B       10/15/13
2       A       10/10/13
2       AX      10/05/13
2       AD      10/03/13
3       DD      10/03/13
```

The outcome should be

```
Number  Status    Date
-----------------------------
1       A       10/20/13
2       A       10/10/13
3       DD      10/03/13
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sample data and expected output both in a tabular format would help to better understand the issue.

Comment: The sample data should be in the question... not in comments :)

Comment: I just added an example.Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **[CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)** with **[ROW_NUMBER()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)** function. Also Please use a `Table JOIN` *instead* `FROM STATUS, OPERATION`

```
;With CTE AS (
   SELECT O.NUMBER, S.STATUS, S.DATE, 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY S.DATE DESC) RN
   FROM  STATUS S JOIN OPERATION O
           ON O.AUTO_KEY = S.AUTO_KEY 
)
SELECT NUMBER, STATUS, DATE
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY NUMBER
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm using Excel to query an Oracle db. it doesn't seem to work with Oracle

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT OPERATION.CNUMBER, 
       STATUS.STATUS, 
       STATUS.CDATE
FROM STATUS, 
     OPERATION
WHERE OPERATION.AUTO_KEY = STATUS.AUTO_KEY 
AND STATUS.CDATE = (
SELECT MAX(STATUS.CDATE) MAX_DATE
FROM STATUS, 
      OPERATION
WHERE OPERATION.AUTO_KEY = STATUS.AUTO_KEY 
GROUP BY OPERATION.CNUMBER )
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm using Excel to query an Oracle db. I get an error message. Missing right parenthesis, I checked I have them all

Comment: I ran the query on a test environment over here, and it was fine. By the way column names cannot be NUMBER or DATE. I fixed that in my answer.

Comment: In order to elaborate more on the my earlier comment. I ran the query against oracle DB (without using Excel)